# Paypal android INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to implement paypal sandbox into my application, i've followed every steps from the https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/in-app/android/ , however after importing everything and when i am trying to start my application i get the following error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/xxx/Desktop/Work/shop_java/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl695433300.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #63): com.paypal.pyplcheckout.home.view.activities.PYPLInitiateCheckoutActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
```

And i don't quite understand why it is,
my Android manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.xxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules">

        <activity android:name=".ProductActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".promotion.PromotionItemActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

However it fails, i tried to rebuild, tried to clean, invalidate caches, gradle runs ok, but when i try to run it says this, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the Library in build.gradle now the last version is 0.6.1.

implementation 'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.6.1'